# Execute dynamic SQL and Insert into a created table in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following Rejects Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rejects](
    [Report Year] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [COS - Country Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Franchise - Style Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Product - Style Code] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have the following SP:

```
DECLARE
    @ReportYearCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @CosCountCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000),
    @ProductCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000);

WITH Validations AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Handshake] WHERE [Status] = 'Loaded' AND [Update Time] = ( SELECT MAX( [Update Time] ) FROM Handshake )
)
UPDATE Validations 
SET 
    @ReportYearCmd = CASE WHEN Report_Year_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] AS [Report Year] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] );'
    END,
    @CosCountCmd = CASE WHEN COS_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] );' 
    END,
    @FranchiseCountCmd = CASE WHEN  Franchise_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Franchise - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    @ProductCountCmd = CASE WHEN Product_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Product - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    [Status] = CASE
        WHEN ( Report_Year_Count = 0 AND COS_Count = 0 AND Franchise_Count = 0 AND Product_Count = 0 ) THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Reject(s)'
    END
FROM [Validations] 
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT 
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] ) ), 0 ) AS [Report_Year_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [COS_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Franchise_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Product_Count]

) AS [ValidationCounts];

-- Return validation sql statements --

SELECT
    @ReportYearCmd AS ReportYearCmd,
    @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd,
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS FranchiseCountCmd,
    @ProductCountCmd AS ProductCountCmd;
```

Currently, when I execute this SP I get something like:

```
ReportYearCmd CosCountCmd FranchiseCountCmd  ProductCountCmd

NULL          SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] )        NULL               SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Product - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] )
```

I'd like to return the actual result, i.e. if the Cmd is NOT NULL, as in the example above, return CosCountCmd and ProductCountCmd data:

```
Report Year COS - Country Code   Franchise - Style Code   Product - Style Code 
NULL        reject1              NULL                     Rejectxy
NULL        reject2              NULL                     Reject1234
NULL        NULL                 NULL                     Reject567
```

I've tried the following but I'm getting syntax errors around `EXEC`

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Rejects]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] (
       [Report Year]
      ,[COS - Country Code]
      ,[Franchise - Style Code]
      ,[Product - Style Code]
)
VALUES (
    IF @ReportYearCmd IS NOT NULL
        EXEC ( @ReportYearCmd );

    IF @CosCountCmd IS NOT NULL
        EXEC ( @CosCountCmd );

    IF @FranchiseCountCmd IS NOT NULL
        EXEC ( @FranchiseCountCmd );

    IF @ProductCountCmd IS NOT NULL
        EXEC ( @ProductCountCmd );
)
```

Comment: Are you looking to insert into the table from inside the proc, or from a script that calls the proc, or ?

Comment: @SteveC from inside the procedure

Comment: Ok, after testing with this for a bit it seems it's attempting to populate the table in a column-wise fashion which doesn't really conform to the relational approach, you could say.  I'm thinking it would be better to take the 4 queries and try to make 1 query out of them

Comment: @SteveC figured it out, this is what i needed to do: `
 TRUNCATE TABLE Rejects IF @ReportYearCmd IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO Rejects ( [Report Year] ) EXEC ( @ReportYearCmd );
    
IF @CosCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO Rejects ( [COS - Country Code] ) EXEC ( @CosCountCmd );
    
IF @FranchiseCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO Rejects ( [Franchise - Style Code] ) EXEC ( @FranchiseCountCmd );
    
IF @ProductCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO Rejects ( [Product - Style Code] ) EXEC ( @ProductCountCmd );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need the insert to be part of the dynamic SQL e.g.

```
SET @ReportYearCmd = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([Report Year]) ' + @ReportYearCmd;
EXEC (@ReportYearCmd);

SET @CosCountCmd = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([COS - Country Code]) ' + CosCountCmd;
EXEC (@CosCountCmd);

SET @FranchiseCountCmd = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([Franchise - Style Code] ) ' + @FranchiseCountCmd;
EXEC (@FranchiseCountCmd);

SET @ProductCountCmd = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([Product - Style Code]) ' + @ProductCountCmd;
EXEC (@ProductCountCmd);
```

Or the insert columns to exactly match the result of the dynamic SQL e.g.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([Report Year])
    EXEC (@ReportYearCmd);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([COS - Country Code])
    EXEC (@CosCountCmd);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([Franchise - Style Code])
    EXEC (@FranchiseCountCmd);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([Product - Style Code])
    EXEC (@ProductCountCmd);
```

Note: As an improvement to your table design I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rejects] (
    [Type] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Error] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and then for example:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([Type], [Error])
    SELECT DISTINCT 'Report Year' AS [Type], [Report Year] AS [Error]
    FROM [Fact]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Report Year]
        WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year]
    );
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221539/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-k-execute-dynamic-sql-and-insert-into-a-created-tab).